# How do I create a date object from a URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a date paramater in my URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/restaurants/1/restaurant_stats.pdf?date=2013-05-02
```

I want to use this date if the parameter exists otherwise use today's date.

```
if params[:date]
 date = Date.new(params[:date].to_i)
else
 date = Date.today
end
```

The above code doesnt work. It sets the date to Jan 01 of the year specified.

Answer (score 4):

```
if params[:date]
 date = Date.parse(params[:date])
else
 date = Date.today
end
```